# jQuery load animation when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to load an animation when you scroll down on the page, I've seen it done on this website: http://spyproof.net/

I would show code samples, but I do not know where to begin with this!

Comment: You can do with wow.js see example: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

Comment: Try waypoints.js, I tried it for same functionality and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use animation library like [wow.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use css animation  [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) it's free you can download and use it